# grep for words separated by dash

Tags: unix, grep

I have a bunch of strings like this that I want to extract from a file with many other strings:

```
 chr2:95183661-95183776
 chr9:951d2483661-95182423776
```

I am looking for a way to grep for this particular pattern, but the dash in the middle causes problems. Here's what I have tried:

```
 grep  -w --color -o -E  "chr[0-9]:[0-9]-[0-9]*"
```

Comment: `grep  --color -oE  "chr[0-9]+:[0-9]+-[0-9]+"`  should work

Comment: indeed it did.!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a testfile, in order to check the regular expression:

```
Prompt> cat test.txt
chr2:95183661-95183776
chr9:951d2483661-95182423776blabla
blabla
```

I have come up with following regular expression:

```
"chr[0-9]*\:[0-9a-z]*\-[0-9]*"
```

With following meaning:

- `[0-9]*`    : any number of digits
- `\:`        : a colon, preceded by a backslash in order to treat it as a real character, not a wildcard.
- `[0-9a-z]*` : any number of small letters or digits
- `\-`        : a hyphen, preceded by a backslash in order to treat it as a real character, not a wildcard (like in `[0-9]`).

Test:

```
Prompt> grep -o "chr[0-9]*\:[0-9a-z]*\-[0-9]*" test.txt
chr2:95183661-95183776
chr9:951d2483661-95182423776
```